# Cplex "reset perspective" and window views does not work

Tags: cplex

I accidently closed the windows in Cplex. Then I tried to open but it didnt work. I tried with Windows menu. I tried "reset perspective" menu. Then I tried to restart program, computer. I reinstalled program. But still doesnt work. I run program admin mode, I run different modes(win10, win7...) but still doesnt work. Is there a configuration file? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In command line can you try

oplide -clean

?